Smooth partitions of unity?
I read some paper of moment of Dirichlet L-function, and they often use approximate functional equation to continue, and some of them use the trick of smooth partition of unity, such as:
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty V\left(\frac{m}{2^k}\right)=1,$$
for all $m\geq1$, where $V$ a smooth function supported on [1,2].
However, I do not see any of them give the proof of smooth partition of unity, I wonder why this operation (the choice of $V$) is actionable, can anyone give some help?

The version you stated is certainly not correct. A smooth functions supported on $[1,2]$ vanishes at $1$ and $2$, so the sum you write vanishes whenever $m$ is a power of $2$. Rather the trick requires smooth functions whose support is a bit bigger than $[1,2]$.
One can choose a smooth function $f$ which is $1$ for $x > 1.1$ and $0$ for $x<.9$ and then let
$$V(x ) = \begin{cases} f(x) & \textrm{ if } x \leq 1.5\\ 1- f(x/2) & \textrm{ if } x \geq 1.5 \end{cases}$$
so that $V(x)$ is supported on $[.9, 2.2]$ and then taking $k$ the minimum value such that $m/2^k \leq 1.5$ we have $V(m/2^k) = f(m/2^k)$, $V(m/2^{k-1}) = 1- f(m/2^k)$, and $V(m/2^{k'})=0$ for all $k' \neq k,k-1$ so the sum is $1$ as desired.

Thank you very much! I get it.

As Will Sawin observes, there is no such function supported on $[1,2]$. For every larger interval $[a, b]$, $a<1<2<b$, you may take your favourite function $f$ supported on $[a, b]$ and positive on $(a, b)$ and put $H(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(2^k x)$ for all positive $x$, (this is a strictly positive smooth function enjoying the property $H(2x)=H(x)$) and put $V(x)=f(x)/H(x)$. Then $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty V(2^k x)=1$ for all $x>0$ and $V$ is supported on $[a, b]$.

Thank you very much! I get it.
